# How to send POST request using flask.redirect?

Tags: python, redirect, post, flask

I'm trying to create a flask service in which I want to send the data coming from one request.form to another url in json format, Please can anyone help me to achieve this?

```
redirect(url_for('any_method'), json = json.dumps(my_form_dict))
```

When I try to execute the above code I'm getting following error:

```
TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json' The above is the error here.
```

Comment: Where's exactly the problem? You have already the solution, just pass `json=request.form` in the first route...

Comment: No this is not the solution. While trying to run with that I'm getting the following error: TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'

Comment: Could you provide more information? What are your current results, what are you expecting? Any error message, some examples...

Comment: TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json' 

The above is the error here..

Comment: Ok, just try to edit the question and add this details to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok Sure, Thanks for the Suggestion

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to redirect POST request itself? If yes - it is not possible to redirect POST requests. More info is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).

Comment: Thanks, @AndrejsCainikovs for clearing me, yes I was trying to send a POST redirect. Your comment cleared everything now..

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I have added my comment as an answer, and will add more info/links as soon as I find them. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to redirect POST requests.
More info is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).

Answer (score 7):

You can redirect POST requests using 307 status code. 
Use:

```
redirect(url_for('any_method', json=json.dumps(my_form_dict)), code=307)
```

For more information refer to this answer:
[Make a POST request while redirecting in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480983/8963778)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing too much arguments to the [redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.redirect) function. It only expects three parameters, `location`, `code`, and `Response`. If you want to pass extra parameters, use the Flask [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.url_for) method:

```py
redirect(url_for('any_method', json=form_json))
```

Note the difference, you were passing the `url_for` and extra fields as two parameters. In my version, I've added the extra fields in the `url_for`, so `redirect` only receives one parameter.

Comment: Did this answer solved your problem? If so, please vote and mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I have tried the above code also but flask's request.json is not working with the above step. I'm not getting the json in the request even after using above way

Comment: Take a look at the request object, maybe you're not sending it as a `form`, try to access `request.data`

Answer (score 0):

I used the `requests` package to redirect a `GET` request to the `POST` one.
The trick is using `flask.make_response()` to make a new `Resposne` object.
In my scenario, the last response is an HTML text, so I get `text` as a response.

```py
from flask import request, make_response
import requests

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    data = {"data": request.args['data']}
    redirect_response = requests.post('https://my-api/login', json=data).text
    return make_response(redirect_response, 302)
```